# winapi - what does WHEEL_DELTA value means?

Tags: c#, winapi, mouseevent

Can someone explain what is 120 value in this code:

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, 120, 0);
```

Is that a number of pixels to scroll up/down?

If not, how can I calculate a number of pixels from that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If dwFlags contains MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, then dwData specifies the
>   amount of wheel movement. A positive value indicates that the wheel
>   was rotated forward, away from the user; a negative value indicates
>   that the wheel was rotated backward, toward the user. One wheel click
>   is defined as WHEEL_DELTA, which is 120.

Comment: What actually happens when you scroll is dependent upon the mouse you are using and how it has been configured.

Comment: And it isn't necessarily 120.  Recommend SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollDelta instead.